# Signing in without asking my credentials after logout from Stack Overflow if have logged in using Google strategy

Tags: support, accounts, logout

After I login to Stack Overflow account through Google option, I logout from Stack Overflow account. Then I click on the login button and select login with Google. Since the Google cookies exist on this machine the login process is successfully done, which in a public place this will allow to next person to access my account.

Is this true?
Should I be concerned about this?

Comment: Yes, it is true. You need to logout from Google as well to be safe.

Comment: Many people may not know or care about this.

Comment: If they don't care why should we?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

You are warned about that on the [Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout) page:

[image: logout with text to logout from Open Id providers as well.]

I give you the term "Open ID provider" might be confusing as that is no longer at play here.

If you do have to use a public computer the least you can do is start a private browsing session and close that private browser window when you're done. That will clean-up all stuff that got stored by the browser during your session, including cookies used for authentication.

Answer (score 4):

Logging in using your Google account logs you into both your Google account and your Stack Overflow account. Logging out of Stack Overflow only logs you out of your Stack Overflow account.

If you want to be logged out of your Google account then you have to go to Google to log out of it.

Yes, you should make sure you log out of your Google account when using a public computer.

If you have forgotten to log out on a public computer you can still end then session by logging into your Google account and:

- Click on your icon
- Choose “Manage Account” from the menu
- Go to “Security”
- Scroll down to “Your Devices”
- Choose “Manage Devices”
- Use the triple dot menu next to the device(s) you don’t own/recognize and choose “log out”